# Finding the "average function" between several nonlinear functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I am looking for some approach which can give an intermediate function among these five different function plots, where this "average function" has the closest distance at each point on the x-axis to each of the five plots.

The plots are shown here for the purpose of the question:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have checked in functional analysis book, and all I could find was the metric which could be applied between functions. That would be an integral. But if this was to be the best way, how can one find the metric between 5 different functions from an integration?

Alternatively, are there better particular methods one can use?

Thanks

Comment: Do you intend to put weights on the different functions in order to privilegize some of them ?

Comment: No, just find a function which satisfies the average of each point of each function, if such a function exists at all.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to optimize here.  What's wrong with just taking the average?

Comment: @lulu Because these functions are long and complex, and I am looking for a way that I can use computationally to give hopefully an analytic function. Having the coordinates would then at best give a function by nonlinear regression. Is that the only way? Have a look at this co.post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600285/how-to-combine-dissimilar-curves-into-a-single-average?noredirect=1#comment1112131_600285

Comment: Again, you haven't said what you are trying to minimize.  I am guessing you meant the sum of squared distances of the points above a given $x$ value.  In that case your function $F(x)$ is just $\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(x)$.  What could be simpler?  But perhaps you meant a different sort of optimization...you really need to specify that.

Comment: Note that those who commented on the post you linked to said exactly the same thing I am saying.  Just take the average. Unless you meant some other sort of distance.

Comment: If  one function is cosx and another is sinx, and the third is cos(2x) , would the average function be simply $(sinx+cosx+cos(2x))/3$?

Comment: Yes, that's the answer, *if* you are  just averaging.

Comment: Hi Lulu, I don't know what you mean by "minimizing".

Comment: I don't see what there is to chat about...I think you need to edit your post to explain what you are trying to optimize.  If the average is not the function you had in mind, please (in your post) explain what's wrong with it.  Preferably with an explicit example.

Comment: Again, you haven't explained what "optimal" property you want your result to have.  "the closest distance at each point on the x-axis to each of the five plots." makes no sense since your function can't be simultaneously closest to *each* of the five points, unless the five points coincide.  I guessed you meant to minimize $\sum (F(x)-f_i(x))^2$ for each $x$ and that's just the average.  But you might have meant something else.

Comment: This last point I am not sure about. So I stick with the "regular" average, since it was also advised on the other post. Thanks for this